# Delphi draw parabola with PlotGird

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using a `PlotGrid` component with Firemonkey and I want to be able to draw a parabola in it. Given a very easy program that takes a,b,c as input ( > ax^2 + bx + c = 0) I am going to solve the 2nd degree equation.

As you should know that can be represented with a parabola. I thought that I could use this procedure:

```
procedure DrawArc(const Center, Radius: TPointF; StartAngle, SweepAngle: Single; const AOpacity: Single); overload;
```

You can see this picture to better understand the meaning:

[image]

I want to be able to draw a parabola in a PlotGrid because the user in this way I can have a "container" for my line. Also, if I resized the component or I am using a mobile device, I won't have to repaint the x/y axis. Is this a good way to go?

---

I have studied a bit the situation and this is what I have thought:

The **focus** coords of the parabola should be what in the procedure are called Center.
The Radius.X should be the value of one of the solutions of the equations. I The Radius.Y should be the position of the **vertex**.

I cannot figure how to setup the sweep angle. Is this too complicated? Should I find another better solution to draw the parabola?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot draw parabola with ellipse arc, it doesn't give needed curve form (only small parabola piece near middle point might be approximated).

If Firemonkey graphics engine supports B[ezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), you can draw exact parabola with Bezier. To calculate it's coefficients, express X- and Y- parts of parametric cubic curve in power basis

```
F(x) = -b/2a + (t - 0.5) * needed_parabola_X_range
F(y) = a*F(x)^2 + b * F(x) + c
```

then transform them into Bernstein polynomial basis (here you need some understanding of [Bezier math](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/))

VCL example

```
var
  a, b, c, w: Double;
  b2a, baw: Double;
  P: array[0..3] of TPoint;
  Cx, Cy: array[0..3] of Double;
begin
  //vertex at (200, 100)
  a := 0.05;
  b := -20;
  c := 2100;
  W := 160; //width, distance between parabola ends
  b2a := - 0.5 * b / a;
  baw := b2a - 0.5 * W;
  Cx[0] := baw;
  Cx[1] := W;
  Cx[2] := 0;
  CX[3] := 0;
  Cy[0] := a * baw * baw + c + b * baw;
  Cy[1] := b * W + 2 * a * W * baW;
  Cy[2] := a * W * W;
  Cy[3] := 0;
  p[0] := Point(Round(Cx[0]), Round(Cy[0]));
  p[1].X := Round(cx[0] + cx[1] / 3);
  p[1].Y := Round(cy[0] + cy[1] / 3);
  p[2].X := Round(cx[0] + (2 * cx[1] + cx[2]) / 3);
  p[2].Y := Round(cy[0] + (2 * cy[1] + cy[2]) / 3);
  p[3].X := Round(cx[0] + cx[1] + cx[2] + cx[3]);
  p[3].Y := Round(cy[0] + cy[1] + cy[2] + cy[3]);
  Canvas.PolyBezier(P);
```

Comment: The values a, b and c are calculated with respect to the y?

Comment: a,b,c are predefined coefficients (author gets them as input). Here I chose values to make vertex at reasonable coordinates